# BlackBerry Cascades UI File Selection

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I have set up a BlackBerry Cascades-UI project. I am using QML to define the look and feel of the user interface. I need to provide the user a method of selecting an image from the device photo gallery after the screen has been touched.

Does anyone have any idea on how to provide a list on the screen with all the images in the gallery and their appropriate names after a touch event has been triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps someone would like to know even though nobody answered.

There currently is no Photo Gallery dialog (though it is announced and will probably be released in an update in the near future). However, it is possible to invoke a native file selection dialog from another thread. For more information about this, go to the support forums for Cascades and find a topic called: "Using native filebrowse and filesave dialog in Cascades".

Here is a [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Using-native-filebrowse-and-filesave-dialog-in-Cascades/td-p/1772481).

Answer (score 4):

on beta 3, you can use [file picker](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__pickers__filepicker.html) to select file(s)

Comment: Which doesn't work on simulator. Which also has problems with file selection on device (as of time of writing).

Comment: yup, it doesn't work on simulator; hopefully it will solved soon by RIM dev.